# How to make my PS1 bash session show the whole pwd at all times?

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc, pwd

Relevant `.bashrc` section:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w \$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Question is, how do I make it not to shorten the `pwd` if in home directory, thus show the whole `pwd` at all times in PS1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by replacing `\w` and `\W` in the `PS1` with `$PWD`:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] $PWD \$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]$PWD \$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h $PWD \$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \$PWD\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```